# What are the new birds in Angry Birds Space?

Tags: angry-birds-space

What are the new birds in *Angry Birds Space* and what are their abilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Angry Birds Nest has a post](http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/official-angry-birds-space-announcement/) with analysis of the announcement video:

> - At first glance, the video suggests that the Red, Black, and [now-green] Big Brother birds all have the same abilities as before, though newly-designed.
> - The Blue birds have the same ability, though they seem a bit stronger than in the original apps.
> - There also seems to be a purple-colored bird (we are not going to speculate as to its name right now), whose ability is to redirect and accelerate. Personally, I believe this is a new ability of the existing Yellow bird.
> - There is also a new “icy” bird (again, no speculation as to name), whose ability is to freeze its contact area on a structure.

This seems to be accurate based on [this newer post](http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/meet-the-birds-in-angry-birds-space/) describing all of the birds in detail, which I won't reproduce.

**Edit:** Based on playing the game just now, it appears that the blue birds don't speed up as mentioned in the latter post (but not the first).  Possibly it was just confirmation bias on ABN's part since there's a nice rocket-like glow when they split apart.  As well, all birds show a plot of the first part of their trajectory.

Comment: The purple bird appears to behave much differently than the old yellow bird. The yellow bird would just accelerate in the direction it was moving at the time, while the purple bird while accelerate in whichever direction you tap no matter it's original path.

Comment: @DoozerBlake I wouldn't call it much different, it's just the redirection -- which is what the excerpt notes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Red: Super Red, Ability: Shouts to scare pigs

Blues: Lightning Birds, Ability: Creates a flash and splits into 3 directions

Chuck: Lazer Bird, Ability: Targets wherever tapped

Bomb: Firebomb, Ability: Blows up

Egg: Space Egg, Ability: creates a wormhole that either sucks or pushes stuff around

Ice Bird, Ability: Freezes everything nearby that can be frozen

Terence: The Incredible Terence, Ability: Roars to scare pigs

Bubbles: Atom Bird, Ability: Expands to huge size

Mighty Eagle: Space Eagle, Ability: Creates a wormhole where the Sardines were dropped and destroys everything in his path.